# How to add a trusted origin to gorilla websocket's CheckOrigin?

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm developing a websocket-based app where the frontend is in vue.js running on port `127.0.0.1:8080` and the backend is in golang running on port `127.0.0.1:3000`.
The frontend is suppose to communicates to:
`serverUrl: "ws://127.0.0.1:3000/ws",`

To avoid CORS problem I had to return `true` for `CheckOrigin`:

```
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  4096,
    WriteBufferSize: 4096,
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}
```

However I know that it is not secure bacuase this leaves the door open to any IP to connect to backed. My question is that how can I limit it so that it only allows request from `127.0.0.1:8080` ?

I've looked at [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gorilla/websocket) but could not find how to do so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Return true from the [CheckOrigin](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Upgrader.CheckOrigin) function if the [origin](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7) is the trusted site.

```
CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
    origin := r.Header.Get("Origin")
    return origin == "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
},
```